# Proper method for discovering BLE services

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I keep getting the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.util.UUID
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getUuid()' on a null object
>   reference

when trying to 'get' a known service and characteristic using UUIDs. The documentation says that I need to discover services first, but I guess I'm doing that incorrectly? Here is my connect method:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public void Connect(View view){

    Device=Adapter.getRemoteDevice("3C:A3:08:94:C3:11");

    Gatt=Device.connectGatt(this,true,GattCallback);

    Gatt.discoverServices();

    Service=Gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000FFE0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

    ErrorID.setText(Service.getUuid().toString());

    Characteristic=Service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000FFE1-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

    threadStatus=true;

    //connected indicator

}
```

The `textView` is there to confirm that the service has been located. I've tried adding delays after `discoverServices()` but that didn't work. Using `onServicesDiscovered()` afterwards also didn't work. I'm new to Java and Android sorry if my question is silly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `GattCallback` in which you override the callback methods. you need to define your `GattCallback` something like code below. And when you receive a callback, perform the appropriate action.

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback GattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                // This is where you call to discover services. 
                Gatt.discoverServices();

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // This is where you will call the method to get the service
                Service=Gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000FFE0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            } else {
            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling

```
Gatt=Device.connectGatt(this,true,GattCallback);
```

you must wait for the [`onConnectionStateChange` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) of your `GattCallback` to be called (with an appropriate status) before doing anything else.

Once that happens, you'll need to call [`discoverServices`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) on your `Gatt` instance, and wait once more for the [`onServicesDiscovered`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onServicesDiscovered(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int)) method of your `GattCallback` to be called.

Only at this point, after `onServicesDiscovered` has been called, can you call `Gatt.getService` and expect to receive a non-`null` result. This is true even if you know what services you expect to exist on the device.